# Requesting specific nodes with TORQUE qsub?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

There's a cluster with TORQUE qsub installed. I want to send a job, but I want to make sure that it runs on one of a specific set of nodes.

Is it possible to request a list of possible nodes in `qsub`, so that the job is sent to one of the nodes in the requested set, never to a node outside the set?

Answer (score 2):

Using just TORQUE, the way to do this is to add a feature (or property) to each of the nodes in the set and add the feature as part of the job request. For example:

```
#nodes file entry
node01 fast np=32

# line in job script to request 2 'fast' nodes with 16 execution slots on each
#PBS -l nodes=2:fast:ppn=16
```

Depending on which scheduler you're using there may be easier ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: I can add a property to a set of nodes without being an admin of the cluster?

Comment: If you're not the admin, you should contact the people who are.  Maybe they already have an answer for this for that specific environment.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt I'm not an admin, and contacting the admins is too much hassle, since they are usually too busy doing other stuff. Is there an alternative way to specify an explicit list of possible nodes for my job?

Comment: @becko you can specify the names of the nodes if using features isn't possible.

Comment: How? I need to specify a list of *alternative* nodes where my job can run. That is, my job needs only *one* of those nodes. Can you give an example? I have looked around the documentation but all I have found is that you can reserve a set of nodes for a job that will use *all* of those nodes, but that's not what I want.

Comment: You can't specify a list of possible nodes to choose from without features for Torque. Depending on the scheduler there may exist options. For example, with Moab you can specify a hostlist to choose from.